# Take input from edit text and save in the list 1 but it will show the list 1 result in other list

Tags: java, android, list, listview, android-intent

I have two classes. First is `MainActivity.java` Second is `EditBox.java` what im trying to do is `MainActivity.java` create 4 list and i want to get data from edit box which is in editbox.java and save in the `list`.when i'm enter in the edit box in `list` 1 it will show the `list` 1 input result in other lists.plz help me what to do
here is the code of

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

         String[] items = { "List 1", "List 2", "List 3","List 4" };


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);



        listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id)
            {

                String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();

                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent it1 =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),editbox.class); 

                startActivity(it1);

            }
        });



    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        menu.add("List").setIntent(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
        return true;
    }

}
```

**EditBox.java**

```
public class editbox extends Activity 
{

    private EditText nameText,nameText1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.editbox);

        nameText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        SharedPreferences setting = getSharedPreferences("List 1",0);
        nameText.setText(setting.getString("List 1", ""));

        nameText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        SharedPreferences setting1 = getSharedPreferences("List 2",0);
        nameText.setText(setting1.getString("List 2", "")); 




    }

    protected void onStop() 
    {

        super.onStop();

        SharedPreferences setting = getSharedPreferences("List 1",0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = setting.edit();
        editor.putString("List 1", nameText.getText().toString());
        editor.commit();

        SharedPreferences setting1 = getSharedPreferences("List 2",0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = setting1.edit();
        editor1.putString("List 2", nameText1.getText().toString());
        editor1.commit();
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        menu.add("List 1").setIntent(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nameText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    SharedPreferences setting = getSharedPreferences("List 1",0);
    nameText.setText(setting.getString("List 1", ""));

// The problem is here
    nameText1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1); // get your second EditText ID here
    SharedPreferences setting1 = getSharedPreferences("List 2",0);
    nameText1.setText(setting1.getString("List 2", ""));
```

Comment: so, You can define(findViewById) only one time. and can you explain that excellently you wont to do.

Comment: get the data from edit txt box and save in the list.when ever i click on the list it will show the data/num

Answer (score 0):

in your Editbox.java why have you only defined one edit text? is it deliberate or you forgot to change it while copying and pasting. try changing the edittext names and R.id.***_*____** and you should be fine

Comment: when u click on the list the editbox activity is open where u enter the num in edit box so same as other list where the editbox is same so  i defined the one editText